# UitextView long text not visible

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, uitextview

Added a long text to UITextView in UITableViewCell and the text is not visible.

```
textView= new UITextView()
            {
                TranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false,
                Font = UIFont.SystemFontOfSize(17f),
                UserInteractionEnabled = true,
                Editable = false,
                ScrollEnabled = false,
                DataDetectorTypes = UIDataDetectorType.Link,
                TextContainerInset = UIEdgeInsets.Zero,
                TextContainer = { LineFragmentPadding = 0 },
            };


textView.Text = text;//Very very long text
```

Comment: where did you set the textView frame?

Comment: I add constraints on uitableviewcell, I calculate the height of the cell

var size = text.StringSize(textView.Font, new CGSize(220f,   Double.MaxValue),UILineBreakMode.WordWrap);

            var height = (int)size.Height + 37;

            return height;

Comment: Which xcode version are you using?

Comment: xcode version 7.2.1

Comment: `textView = new UITextView() {` line of code is giving error in my case, Xcode 7.3.1. How are you able to get it work?

Comment: You write on Swift? it xamarin

Comment: Oh my Bad, didn't see that. Can't help you. :(

Comment: in other languages also have this problem with a lot of text in UITextView